# Conditionally select from one table or another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, how do I select from another table if a foreign key is set?

What I'm trying to do is select `Fields.value` if `Fields.value_id` isn't set, otherwise select `Values.value` from `Values` where `Value.id` is equal to `Fields.value_id`.

My tables:

`Fields:`

`id | value | value_id`

`Values:`

`id | value`

What's wrong with my code here?

Code:

`SELECT CASE 
    WHEN Field.value_id = NULL OR Field.value_id = "" 
        THEN Field.value 
    ELSE 
        Value.value 
    FROM values as Value 
        WHERE (Field.value_id = Value.id)`

Answer (score 2):

One syntax error is that you are missing the `end` in the `case`.  I also think you want a left join between the tables.  My best guess given the available information is this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN f.value_id = NULL OR f.value_id = '' 
             THEN f.value 
             ELSE v.value 
        END)
FROM fields f left join
     values v
     on f.value_id = v.id;
```

Comment: Hm, that's still throwing a syntax error. I accidentally had a typo in my original post (`fieldtype` instead of `field`)- I've updated with a correction and table structure.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. If I tweak it a little bit and point it at a different table that's linked the same way, I get a `Cardinality Error` instead. Is `Value` or `values` a restricted word in MySQL?

Comment: @schnauss . . . `values` is a reserved word.  I didn't bother escaping it, because you were using the name in your question.  (The list of reserved words is here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: Thanks, looks like a little re-engineering is in order!